# Return list of Students by ZipCode Count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a list of students that live in the same zip code where zip code count > 1.

I tried the following and get nothing in my query. If I remove s.Student, I get results of zipcode and count, but I want to include student also.

```
SELECT s.Student, z.ZipCode, COUNT(s.ZipCodeId) As 'Zip Code Count'
FROM Students s
INNER JOIN ZipCodes z ON z.ZipCodeId = s.ZipCodeId
GROUP BY s.Student, z.ZipCode
HAVING COUNT(z.ZipCode) > 1
```

Below are the database tables I am using.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Instructors](
    [InstructorId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Instructor] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ZipCodeId] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Students](
    [StudentId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Student] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ZipCodeId] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ZipCodes](
    [ZipCodeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ZipCode] [varchar](9) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [State] [varchar](25) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: `COUNT(z.ZipCode) > 1` will never be true, because you are returning a row per student. In fact your grouping does nothing.

Comment: As well as the table definitions, we need some sample data to work with.

Comment: I've removed the un-necessary database create stuff to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to query the Zip Codes which are used more than once, then join the Students on along with the Zip Code details e.g.

```
SELECT S.Student, Z.ZipCode, Z1.Num AS "Zip Code Count"
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) Num, ZipCodeId
    FROM Students S
    GROUP BY ZipCodeId
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) Z1
INNER JOIN Students S on S.ZipCodeId = Z1.ZipCodeId
INNER JOIN ZipCodes Z on Z.ZipCodeId = Z1.ZipCodeId;
```

Note: You don't use single quotes (`'`) to delimit a column name - you use double quotes (`"`) or square brackets (`[]`).

Also, sample data would allow testing of our solutions.

Comment: Could just use a window function, probably more performant

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a window function, *without* re-joining

```sql
SELECT
  S.Student,
  Z.ZipCode,
  Z.Num AS [Zip Code Count]
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY S.ZipCodeId) Num
    FROM Students S
) S
INNER JOIN ZipCodes Z on Z.ZipCodeId = S.ZipCodeId
WHERE S.Num > 1;
```